# the COM class factory for component with CLSID Error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {000209FF-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following error: 80080005 Server execution failed (0x80080005 (CO_E_SERVER_EXEC_FAILURE)).

this error show when use Microsoft interop word and excel library
=> Already All permission set but not solve
=> use Microsoft office 2016

please give solution

wordApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();

when hosting site this error show

solve the error immediately

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft does not recommend or support automating Office applications on servers without displaying the user interface (UI)" and recommends using an alternative approach, such as the `Open XML SDK`.

*Here is the related link:*

[Office server-side Automation still possible with Office 365?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61637198/7687666)

Why it works in you dev machine, because the users typically log in and have access to the desktop, which allows the GUI of Office applications to load and execute normally.